# How to disable gcc warning "floating constant exceeds range" and "floating constant truncated to zero"?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, warnings

These obnoxious warnings are on-by-default in current gcc, and I can't find which option is needed to disable them. They're generating warning-spam and preventing compiling with `-Werror` in code where the behavior gcc warns about is intentional (and comes from general-purpose macros that could not easily avoid generating such constants).

Comment: Of course `-w` disables it, but then there's no way to turn the sane warnings back on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging through the GCC source code, I found that the warnings you've described are part of the `-Woverflow` option. So just turn off that warning.

By the way, this comment is in the code for the warning:

> Both C and C++ require a diagnostic for a floating constant
>   outside the range of representable values of its type...
>   We also give a warning if the value underflows.

Comment: Accepted! Don't know how I missed that - I guess I was looking for something floating-point specific since `-Woverflow` only dealt with integer overflow (which is UB and thus a programming error) in earlier gcc versions.

Comment: And OK, I guess I can credit the nuisance to the standards bodies instead of GCC this time...

Comment: @R Do you know what constant gave this warning? I'd be interested to see how a human being overflows a real number.

Comment: There are several cases, but one of them was in a unit test for parsing floating point numbers. Part of the test was that the function correctly parsed numbers which would overflow to `INF`. Naturally the test framework uses a macro that stringizes its argument to pass to the parsing function and compares the result against the value of the argument. One particular value was `1.234e56789`. :-)

Comment: My previous comment about the standard was wrong. Assuming IEEE754/Annex F, the range of `double` is [-INF,INF] **including the endpoints** and there is no value that "exceeds the range" of `double`. This warning from GCC is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In GCC 4.8, each warning comes with a clear indicator of which flag enables it:

```
floating constant exceeds range of 'double' [-Woverflow]
```

Good job, GCC devs.